# how to use RowsAffected in gorm golang

Tags: go, go-gorm

i created a function in repository
however I get an error on RowsAffected

```
func (r *repositoryUser) EntityResultAllTotal(search string) (*models.ModelUser, error) {
    cari := "%" + search + "%"
    var users []models.ModelUser
    result := r.db.Where("username = ?", cari).Find(&users).Error
    return result.RowsAffected
        // result.RowsAffected undefined (type error has no field or method RowsAffected)
}
```

how to solve ?

Comment: [`Find`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.Find) returns [`*gorm.DB`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB) which has field `Error` of type `error` and a field `RowsAffected` of type `int`. If you need both the error and the rows affected you should store the result of `Find` (i.e., the `*gorm.DB`) in a variable and then reference the two fields from that.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `RowsAffected` value you've to use `.RowsAffected` instead of `.Error` after the `Find` method. I rewrote your code as follows:

```golang
func (r *repositoryUser) EntityResultAllTotal(search string) (*models.ModelUser, error) {
    cari := "%" + search + "%"
    var users []models.ModelUser
    rowsAffected := r.db.Where("username = ?", cari).Find(&users).RowsAffected
    return rowsAffected
}
```

Let me know if it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way:

```
func (r *repositoryUser) EntityResultAllTotal(search string) (*models.ModelUser, error) {
    var(
      users []models.ModelUser
      cari = fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%", search)
    )
    result := r.db.Where("username = ?", cari).Find(&users)
    if result.Error != nil {
        return users, result.Error
    }

    fmt.Println(result.RowsAffected) // returns int64
    return users, nil
}
```